# findviewwithtag gives null when recyclerview gets scrolled

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am having a custom gallery implemented with recyclerView, I want to deselect the selected items from other fragment.

To do that I have set a tag to each view as -

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(GalleryAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        String gitem = galleryList.get(i);
        viewHolder.itemView.setTag(gitem); // Setting the tag
        ....
    }
```

to deselect I am finding the view by tag as -

```
recyclerView_gallery.findViewWithTag(String.valueOf(showImageView.getTag())).performClick();
```

It is working when a gallery recyclerview scroll is on that Image but when I scroll down and go to that fragment  - `findViewWithTag` is returning null, but when I scroll to that Image and again do same I found no error.

I have tried this -

```
recyclerView_gallery.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(position);
recyclerView_gallery.findViewWithTag(String.valueOf(showImageView.getTag())).performClick();
```

also, I have tried -

```
recyclerView_gallery.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
```

but the result is the same, it not working if recyclerView gets scrolled.

Answer (score 2):

RecyclerViews recycle all views which are not currently visible to same memory.

This means if you scroll too far the view just doens't have the tag anymore so `findViewWithTag` will return null.

What i would do is setup a List somewhere which contains all items that are supposed to be selected and then check each time in the `onBindViewHolder` and perform an action accordingly. This method get's called each time an item is scrolled into/out of the screen.

The code could look something like this:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public List<String> selectedTags = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onBindViewHolder was called for position: " + position);

        TextView textView = ((ViewHolder) holder).textView;
        textView.setTag(tags.get(position));
        textView.setOnClickListener(...)

        if (selectedTags.contains(textView.getTag())) {
            Log.d("TAG", position + " do something with this item.");
            textView.performClick();
        }
    }
...
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        List<String> someTags = new ArrayList<>();
        someTags.add("someTags");

        ((RecyclerViewAdapter) recyclerView.getAdapter()).tags = someTags;
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Recycler view creates only 4 or 5 views more than the visible view count and rebinds/reuses the views that are not visible to user and hence it is called RecyclerView. OnCreateView method is called to create the required views and onBindViewHolder is called every time the view is bound with data.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(GalleryAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    String gitem = galleryList.get(i);
    viewHolder.itemView.setTag(gitem); // Setting the tag
    ....
}
```

When the view is bound with data "A" , its tag is "A" and when it is reused for item "B", its tag becomes "B" and so when you uses findViewByTag("A"), it returns null because the tag has already changed into "B". You can disable this feature by wrapping the recycler view inside a NestedRecyclerView since NestedRecyclerView creates all the views required and there will not be no view reusing. (It is very easy, but I would not recommend it).

The other approach is to save the selected items/itemId somewhere like this. Suppose your galleryList is a String list,

```
private Set<String> selectedItemList = new HashSet<>();
private List<String> galleryList = new ArrayList<>();

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String gItem = galleryList.get(position);
    holder.populateUi(gItem); //populate normal ui
    if (selectedItemList.contains(gItem)) {
        holder.markSelected(); //mark the ui as selected
    } else {
        holder.markUnSelected(); //mark the ui as unSelected
    }
}
```

and I think you can get the position of the clicked item somehow, if so you may update the ui as follow.

```
public void notifySelected(int... positions) {
    for (int position:positions) {
        String gItem = galleryList.get(position);
        selectedItemList.add(gItem);
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
}

public void notifyUnSelected(int... positions) {
    for (int position:positions) {
        String gItem = galleryList.get(position);
        selectedItemList.remove(gItem);
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
}
```

If you can't get the position, but the item only, you may change like this

```
int index= galleryList.indexOf(item);
if(index>-1){
    selectedItemList.add(galleryList.get(index));
}
```

The better approach is to use the [itemChanged Method with payload](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemChanged(kotlin.Int,%20kotlin.Any)) as it is smoother.
Sorry for code style, as I hadn't coded in Java for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

As @WHOA mentioned

> When the view is bound with data "A", its tag is "A" and when it is reused for item "B", its tag becomes "B" and so when you use findViewByTag("A"), it returns null because the tag has already changed into "B".

And it is a possible reason why you can't find your view by tag. But I don't suggest you save any other list with ids or selected tags. Instead of this, you can add a boolean field to your data model which will tell your adapter is it selected or not or you can create a wrapper for your model with the same field (Idk what is better for your case). Then you will be sure about is item selected or not, also you will be able to store your data as selected/unselected in database or another storage.

Some code samples to be clear:
Adapter

```
class RvAdapter(private val items: List<ListItem>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {

fun selectItems(vararg ids: Int) {
    items.filter { ids.contains(it.id) }
            .forEach { it.isSelected = true }
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun unSelectItems(vararg ids: Int) {
    items.filter { ids.contains(it.id) }
            .forEach { it.isSelected = true }
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    return MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false))
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentItem = items[position]
    holder.bind(currentItem)
}
}
```

ViewHolder:

```
class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
fun bind(item: ListItem) {
    (itemView as TextView).text = item.id.toString()
    itemView.isSelected = item.isSelected // you decide how to mark your view as selected/unselected
}
}
```

And ListItem (change id: Int on whatever you need):

```
data class ListItem(val id: Int, var isSelected: Boolean)
```

IMO, in this way, it will be more clear for you and other people to read this code or edit in the future.
Hope it will help!