# Is is possible to permanently identify item in recyclerview? findviewwithtag sometimes returns null

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I don't understand how .settag() is working in case it is set in RecyclerViewAdapter. This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    try {
        JSONObject _temp_json_object = new JSONObject( String.valueOf( mData.get( position ) ) );
    
        holder.tv_rssi.setText( _temp_json_object.getJSONObject( "Wifi" ).getString( "RSSI" ));
    
        final String _topic = _temp_json_object.getString("Topic");
    
        holder.tv_topic.setTag( _topic );
        holder.tv_topic.setText( _topic );
        }
    ...
```

Later when trying to access this tag using findViewWithTag, sometimes it returns correct TextView id, but sometimes returns null and my code fails. Sometimes means, I exactly dont know what is the trigger, but usually it happens when application goes to background and it is resumed, then findviewwithtag returns null.

```
if (RecyclerView.findViewWithTag( _received_topic ) != null) {

    _arrayList.set( _new_obj );
    _adapter_rv.notifyItemChanged(id); //previously calculated id in json array position

}
```

I found in different post [in this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62618909/findviewwithtag-gives-null-when-recyclerview-gets-scrolled)

that by view recycling mechanism, views will be reused and .settag() information is lost.

Because my aim is to update items with live data I somehow need to keep persistant information about each item to know what to update as online data will arrive.

any idea how to achieve this? if there is better way then using .settag() please let me know. still learning :-)

BTW I was using exactly same method of marking items in GridView and .settag() was persistant, problem is related only to RecyclerView

Answer (score 1):

`findViewWithTag()` is questionable, while the adapter has stable ID. And since you don't disclose why you even try to access these items, I can only tell that accessing the views is useless, since one can handle quite everything through the adapter.

Comment: I hope i did disclosed. There are live date coming from MQTT broker to the app. capturing MQTT JSON formated messages, putting them into JSONArray using .put method. Later the JSONArray is propagated to RecyclerView adapter calling notifyDataSetChanged() or notifyItemChanged(). It depends of we create new JSONObject or updating existing. So I need to exactly know to which item i need to write updated JSON data.

Comment: What Martin is saying is you should loop through your `mData` in your adapter to find if anything exists instead of using `findViewWithTag`

Comment: One doesn't need to touch the views at all, therefore `findViewWithTag()` is irrelevant... the messages just need some unique identifier and the adapter needs `setHasStableIds(true)`. It's quite a one-way road, that's why data-manipulation should happen in the adapter; `RecyclerView` is nothing but the presentation layer (and items outside of the viewport are not even attached) - on the other hand, the adapter knows it all.

Comment: many thanks for pointing to `setHasStableIds(true) ` I will review my code